# how to create a form elements with value in moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to create a form element text with value in moodle. 
I trying the below :

```
$mform->addElement('text','test', get_string('test'));
```

This is used to create a text box . i want to add value also like

```
<input type='text' value='<?php .... ?>' />
```

How to do that in moodle

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the form, you can pass the relevant data into it, e.g.

```
$form = new my_form();
$formdata = (object)array('test' => 'The value to display in the textbox');
$form->set_data($formdata);
```

(Usually the data passed into the form is some existing data retrieved from the database).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of data did you mean here.

If you want to set user data (for example, you are developing a form that edits existing record), then use $form->set_data() after creating a form instance as Davo suggested.

If you want to pre-fill the form with default value, then use this inside the form definition:

```
$mform->addElement('text','test', get_string('test'));
$mform->setDefault('test', 'your default value');
```

You can use both methods, in which case the data from set_data() will have priority.